# Iterating over a QList backwards

Tags: c++, qt, iterator

If I execute the following code:

```
QList<int> l;
QList<int>::const_iterator lI;

l.append(1);
l.append(2);
l.append(3);
l.append(4);
lI = l.constEnd();

while(lI != l.constBegin()) {
  std::cout << *lI << std::endl;
  --lI;
}
```

I get this output:

```
17
4
3
2
```

I already solved it by using the `QListIterator<int>`, but I really don't get why this isn't working!

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: In the first iteration you're dereferencing an end iterator. These are not dereferencable and you're invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: Then I don't understand why it is working the other way around! If you set lI to constBegin, change the if-condition to ask for constEnd and increment the iterator in each iteration, then you get the correct output.

Comment: `begin()` == first element, `end()` == one past the end.  That's why it works the other way around.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks for the help, I didn't know that end() isn't pointing to the last element. Therefore, you only have to decrement before you use the node value.

```
while(lI != l.constBegin()) {
  --lI;
  std::cout << *lI << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
lI = l.constEnd() - 1;
```

I'm not sure if that solves your problem, but as far as I know, end iterators always point one past the end of the container.

I just wanted to address your concern in the comments. When you do this:

```
lI = l.constEnd();

while(lI != l.constBegin()) {
  std::cout << *lI << std::endl;
  --lI;
}
```

You start off the end of the container, and the loop never reaches `constBegin`. That's because when you decrement, `lI` becomes `constBegin` and the while loop doesn't execute. (That's why 1 is never outputted.)

But if you do:

```
lI = l.constBegin();

while(lI != l.constEnd()) {
  std::cout << *lI << std::endl;
  ++lI;
}
```

The same thing happens, except the loop terminates once it reaches `constEnd`. Logically it makes sense, as if `constEnd` didn't point past the end of the container, it would cut off and not output 4.

Comment: Thanks, this doesn't fully solve my problem, but I came up with a solution. You've to change the position of the decrementation. I'll add this in a new answer ...

Comment: lI = l.constEnd() - 1; is a mistake. If the list is empty, l.constBegin() == l.constEnd(), so you should never use l.constEnd() - 1 unless you are certain that list is not empty.